# Dependency injection between Web API and MVC projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I'm working on a solution that contains 4 projects and I'd like to share the same dependency injection pattern.

**The projects**
**Project A**: MVC project with views and controllers that use DI.
**Project B**: WebAPI project with controllers that use DI.
**Project C**: Cache project, the layer that allow me to store and retrieve data in the cache memory.
**Project D**: Services project, the layer of services that store and retrieve data in database (and in cache).

**Project A** and **project B** refer to **project D**. (ex. They ask to the service layer the data and it gives them the data retrieved from database or from cache). (***project A** and **project B** have *IServiceManager* injected in each controller constructor*).

**Project D** refers to **project C** because sometimes it needs data from cache memory and when it updates records on database, it purges the cache. (*it has a ICacheManager injected in the constructor*).

**The problem**
**Project A** and **project B** use the same way to retrieve and store data: they have a *IServiceManager* injected in the constructor for each controller and they call the ServiceManager method.
But when **project B** write a record on database (*using the ServiceManager that should write on db and purge the cache*), and then **project A** read data (using ServiceManager), **project A** continues to "see" old data stored in cache.

**Expectations**
I'd like that DI gives to **project A** and **project B** the same objects (same service and same cache manager) so they can work on the same data.

Is it possible? How can I "centralize" a DI pattern used by **A** and **B** in the same way that gives the same data?

Comment: Do you have the scope to use something like [Redis](https://redis.io/)?

Comment: I prefer not to use Redis or similar, but if there is no alternative I will go on that.

Comment: @Teo Hi. Do you find the answer for this question?
I have something similar